# how to call rules messages validation jquery in if condition

Tags: jquery

I want to call jquery rules,messages validation when mobile number is empty so I wrote code like this but unable to get jquery validations for this code

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            var mobileNumber = $("#mobileNumber").val();
            // alert(mobileNumber);
            if (mobileNumber == "")
            {


                $("form[name='mobnumber']").validate({
                    rules: {
                        mobileNumber: {
                            required: true
                   },
                    },
                    messages: {
                        mobileNumber: {
                            required: "Enter Mobile Number"
                   },
                    },
                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                        form.submit();
                    }
                });

            } else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('test'); ?>",
                    data: {mobileNumber: mobileNumber},
                    success: function (result) {

                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

But validations not calling..How to put jquery validitions in if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put condition of `mobilenumber == ""` remove that and add ajax code inside the `submitHandler()` that will validate the required validation.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            var mobileNumber = $("#mobileNumber").val();
            $("form[name='mobnumber']").validate({
                rules: {
                    mobileNumber: {
                        required: true
                    },
                },
                messages: {
                    mobileNumber: {
                        required: "Enter Mobile Number"
                    },
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url('test'); ?>",
                        data: {mobileNumber: mobileNumber},
                        success: function (result) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: validation is working ,but submit button not working after given validations

Comment: What exactly happening?

Comment: after validation ajax call not happening i mean it is not redirecting to that url page

Comment: you can add redirect code after ajax success response. `window.location.href=your_url`

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like  this

here the validation happens even before your ajax call is completed.

to accomplish this we have simply added `$(value).val().trim().length`

and `$(value).val() != null` you can even validate if the number is of certain length or not

https://jsfiddle.net/neefe7cm/